# .htaccess redirection based on path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a small change to a .htaccess file, related to path and redirection.
I will have different languages on a website, example:

domain.com/fr  - French site
domain.com/ru - Russian site

and pages on the site, example:
domain.com/fr/contact
domain.com/ru/contact

there will be no sub directly on the server like "fr" or "ru", instead i want to define all languages supported in .htaccess file, so that if user visits in browser a page like:

"domain.com/fr/contact"

then .htaccess rules will direct to script:

domain.com/translate.pl?fr/contact

translate.pl will display correct language/page, but still show in browser original page "domain.com/fr/contact".

If user is visiting in browser, example: domain.com/fr/contact  and clicks another page like "domain.com/faq", htaccess will keep the same language. If the user was on the "ru" site, then it will show "domain.com/ru/faq" if user clicked link "domain.com/faq".

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you want to use an internal rewrite. For the second part, you need to use an external redirect. To get the second part to work, you probably want to use a cookie:

The first part is simple. If the url already contains a language, we internally rewrite it to translate.pl. Besides that, we set a cookie with the current language. Refer to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) for more information about the CO-flag. You might need to use the QSA flag if you can call the original url with a query string.

```
#Internal redirect
RewriteRule ^(fr|ru)/(.*)$ /translate.pl?$1/$2 [L,CO=lang:$1:127.0.0.1:1000:/:0:1]
```

The second part might be a little bit more tricky. You need to redirect the user if that cookie is set, but you also need to redirect if the cookie isn't set. We only need to redirect if the url doesn't already contain a language identifier.

```
#Redirect if we know the previous language
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(GET|POST)\ /(ru|fr)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=(ru|fr)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [R,L]

#Redirect if we don't know the previous language
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(GET|POST)\ /(ru|fr)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=(ru|fr)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ru/$1 [R,L]
```

This code is untested, but it should work in theory. You'll obviously need to change the domain for the cookie. You also should make sure that all links on a page in a certain language contain that language identifier, just to make your site a bit more search-engine and user-friendly. Change the `R` flag in the above example to `R=301` if, and only if, everything works as you expect.